# Android folder app with camera button

Tags: android, camera, directories

I'm wondering, is there an Android folder app that permits you to create a folder, with a photo button integrated into the folder that when pressed, gives you the option to take a photo and then store it in that particular folder instead of the usual picture folder?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across two that will work, they dont have a button.  But both allow you to chose a folder to save the photo in.

[Multi Folder Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=m_kunthe.securesoft_net.mulfolcam.multi_folder_camera)

> If you have used camera which am sure you have, you might noticed all your photos gets captured to same DCIM camera folder. . .
>
> This apps helps you capture photos directly to different folders. . .

[Clean Camera - Quick Folder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.creatyf.quick.folder.camera)

> Clean Camera - Quick Folder Camera
>
> Clean Camera allows you to manage your photos right before taking photos. Select a folder direct from the camera view and settings page, feel free to create a custom folder for your photos.
>
> Easily manage folder. Remove, copy, and move your photos to another folder.